# How to get Python-like code folding for C-style languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
// This is a comment
    // stuff 
    // stuff 
    // stuff


// second comment
    // stuff 
    // stuff
```

For C-style languages (Javascript, C++, C#) when the above code is folded it turns into:

```
// This is a comment
// second comment
```

I'd prefer that the whitespace be maintained, meaning after folding the code would look like

```
// This is a comment


// second comment
```

The behavior I prefer was recently implemented for python (which is fantastic)
But I would still HIGHLY appreciate being able to choose myself for every language.

Does anyone know of a way to change this behavior for C-style languages?

Martin Aeschelimann (one of the devs involved with the code folding) said he had added the following code to language configuration settings of the relevant languages

```
"folding": {
    "offSide": true
}
```

However, it seems adding this in vs code language-specific settings doesn't effect javascript. I also looked through all the options javascript did have and none of them seemed related to code folding.

Here are the GitHub links discussing the topic 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3353 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36145

This will likely need to be answered as an issue on GitHub by someone close to the code, probably Martin Aeschlimann or Aaron Shumway. But I was going to try Stack overflow first.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing out that the question wasn't very clear.